# Using custom collection types as backing fields

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is it possible to have a custom collection type as a backing field in Entity Framework Core 3?

I have an entity A that has a OwnsMany relationship with an entity B. Since there are many business rules that needed to be checked before adding B to A, I have to rely on methods like `AddB`, `GetB` and `RemoveB` in order to enforce this rules.

```
    public class Id { ... }
    public class B{
      private A _a;
      internal B(A a){
        _a = a;
      }
      private B() {
        _a = default!;
      }
    }
    public class A {
      private List<B> _bs;
      public IReadOnlyCollection<B> Bs => _bs.AsReadOnly();
      public B AddB() {
        // validate stuff
        var b = new B(this);
        _bs.Add(b);
        return b;
      }
      public B GetB(Id id) { 
        //some linq to find B or throw if id not found
      }
      public B? FindB(Id id) {
        return null if id not found
      }
      public void RemoveB(B b) 
        => _bs.Remove(b);
    }
```

Here the thing is that, as the business rules for managing B, A class is becoming more populated with methods like `DoSomethingForB`, most of them being linq queries or methods that perform calculations over the collection. And if I add another collection of class `C` then the complexity of A increases. So I would like to delegate linq queries and `Get` and `Find` methods to collection classes instead of relying on the generic `List<T>` method.

```
    public class Id { ... }
    public class B{
      private A _a;
      internal B(A a){
        _a = a;
      }
      private B() {
        _a = default!;
      }
    }
    public class BCollection : IEnumerable<B> {
      private List<B> _items;
      public B GetB(Id id) { 
        //some linq to find B or throw if id not found
      }
      public B? FindB(Id id) {
        return null if id not found
      }
      internal void Add(B b) => _items.Add(b);
      // add some other methods like Remove etc. 
    }
    public class A {
      private BCollection _bs;
      public BCollection Bs => _bs;
      public A() {
        _bs = new BCollection();
      }
      public B AddB() {
        // validate stuff
        var b = new B(this);
        _bs.Add(b);
        return b;
      }
    }
```

However, I am unsure whether this is a supported scenario on EF Core 3, specifically if EF Core 3 will know how to reconstruct my `BCollection` type, or if I have to follow some specific rules (perhaps implement an interface or do some special configuration in the `DbContext` configuration).

Thanks in advance.